# MAMP 3.2.1 Upgrade Issue: Local sites ask for wordpress installation process but won't configure

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, mamp

I have recently upgraded to MAMAP 3.2.1 and all works fine (MAMP starts fine, I can access the start page, I can see my local sites listed at localhost:8888/) up to a crucial point:

When I try to access one of my local sites (eg 'localhost:8888/mysite') I am taken to the Wordpress installation page (eg 'localhost:8888/mysite/wp-admin/install.php').

These are sites that I have been developing and accessing up until now to develop. I have tried going through the process of installation but all breaks down at step 2 where I see a list of database errors

> WordPress database error: [Incorrect information in file: '.\mysite\wp_users.frm']
>   CREATE TABLE wp_users ( ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, user_login varchar(60) NOT NULL default '', user_pass varchar(64) NOT NULL default '', user_nicename varchar(50) NOT NULL default '', user_email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', user_url varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', user_registered datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', user_activation_key varchar(60) NOT NULL default '', user_status int(11) NOT NULL default '0', display_name varchar(250) NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KEY (ID), KEY user_login_key (user_login), KEY user_nicename (user_nicename) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8

There is a long list of these database errors.

I'm hoping that this is simple to fix but I've looked everywhere and cannot seem to find anybody experiencing a similar problem. I also hope I've explained the problem thoroughly enough. For reference I'm on a PC.

Your help would be hugely appreciated!